# i want to get all user data with data on behalf of batch_id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

i want to get data in instructor dashboard on the behalf of batches assigned to them from order product table where if user buy single course then we get batch id and if user buy package(package include multiple batch_ids) then batch id = 0 match batch id from package details field(package details field contain json data like batch_ids, package id, package detail etc.)

```
$orders = OrderProduct::get();
$temp = OrderProduct::join('packages', 'order_products.package_id', '=', 'packages.package_id')->where('order_products.status', '=', '1')->pluck('batch_ids')->toArray();
    
     
        if(!empty($temp))
        {
            foreach($temp as $item)
            {
                dd($item);
                $batch = Batch::whereIn('id','=',explode(',', $item))->get();
                dd($batch);
            }
        }
```

Comment: First you can't use = in whereIn. Refrence Code: $batch = Batch::whereIn('id' ,explode(',', $item))->get();

Answer (score 0):

The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array. *whereIn* method does not use **=** sign.

Below is correct way to use **whereIn**:

```
   $batch = Batch::whereIn('id',explode(',', $item))->get();
```

See more about Laravel [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)